# Given a date range how can we break it up into N contiguous sub-intervals?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, python-datetime

I am accessing some data through an API where I need to provide the date range for my request, ex. start='20100101', end='20150415'.  I thought I would speed this up by breaking up the date range into non-overlapping intervals and use multiprocessing on each interval.

My problem is that how I am breaking up the date range is not consistently giving me the expected result.  Here is what I have done:

```
from datetime import date

begin = '20100101'
end = '20101231'
```

Suppose we wanted to break this up into quarters. First I change the string into dates:

```
def get_yyyy_mm_dd(yyyymmdd):
    # given string 'yyyymmdd' return (yyyy, mm, dd)
    year = yyyymmdd[0:4]
    month = yyyymmdd[4:6]
    day = yyyymmdd[6:]
    return int(year), int(month), int(day)

y1, m1, d1 = get_yyyy_mm_dd(begin)
d1 = date(y1, m1, d1)
y2, m2, d2 = get_yyyy_mm_dd(end)
d2 = date(y2, m2, d2)
```

Then divide this range into sub-intervals:

```
def remove_tack(dates_list):
    # given a list of dates in form YYYY-MM-DD return a list of strings in form 'YYYYMMDD'
    tackless = []
    for d in dates_list:
        s = str(d)
        tackless.append(s[0:4]+s[5:7]+s[8:])
    return tackless

def divide_date(date1, date2, intervals):
    dates = [date1]
    for i in range(0, intervals):
        dates.append(dates[i] + (date2 - date1)/intervals)
    return remove_tack(dates)
```

Using begin and end from above we get:

```
listdates = divide_date(d1, d2, 4)
print listdates # ['20100101', '20100402', '20100702', '20101001', '20101231'] looks correct
```

But if instead I use the dates:

```
begin = '20150101'
end = '20150228'
```

...

```
listdates = divide_date(d1, d2, 4)
print listdates # ['20150101', '20150115', '20150129', '20150212', '20150226']
```

I am missing two days at the end of February.  I don't need time or timezone for my application and I don't mind installing another library.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would actually follow a different approach and rely on timedelta and date addition to determine the non-overlapping ranges

**Implementation**

```
def date_range(start, end, intv):
    from datetime import datetime
    start = datetime.strptime(start,"%Y%m%d")
    end = datetime.strptime(end,"%Y%m%d")
    diff = (end  - start ) / intv
    for i in range(intv):
        yield (start + diff * i).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    yield end.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

**Execution**

```
>>> begin = '20150101'
>>> end = '20150228'
>>> list(date_range(begin, end, 4))
['20150101', '20150115', '20150130', '20150213', '20150228']
```

Comment: Works great! Concise and without all of my intermediate functions.  Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed something that perhaps you may wish to edit.  In your answer: yield (d1 + diff * i).strftime("%Y%m%d"), d1 is a global and works with my code, but in general d1 should be start.

Comment: @Scott: Thank you. My original code was with d1, d2 variables but later changed it to some thing meaningful in this post but seemingly missed  couple of edits.

Answer (score 7):

```
# create bins
bins = pd.date_range(start='2020-12-27', end='2022-11-27', periods=3)

bins
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-12-27', '2021-12-12', '2022-11-27'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

# cut into intervals
pd.cut(df['datetime_col'], bins=bins)
```

Comment: This answer seems to bring new idea to the question (probably `date_range` was not in pandas at the time of the question, or else it is strange that nobody thought of that). But it could be better with some explanation; code only answer are discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use the datetime.date objects instead?

If you do:

```
import datetime
begin = datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2010, 12, 31)

intervals = 4

date_list = []

delta = (end - begin)/4
for i in range(1, intervals + 1):
    date_list.append((begin+i*delta).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

and date_list should have the end dates for each inteval.

Answer (score 3):

you should change date for datetime

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

begin = '20150101'
end = '20150228'

def get_yyyy_mm_dd(yyyymmdd):
  # given string 'yyyymmdd' return (yyyy, mm, dd)
  year = yyyymmdd[0:4]
  month = yyyymmdd[4:6]
  day = yyyymmdd[6:]
  return int(year), int(month), int(day)

y1, m1, d1 = get_yyyy_mm_dd(begin)
d1 = datetime(y1, m1, d1)
y2, m2, d2 = get_yyyy_mm_dd(end)
d2 = datetime(y2, m2, d2)

def remove_tack(dates_list):
  # given a list of dates in form YYYY-MM-DD return a list of strings in form 'YYYYMMDD'
  tackless = []
  for d in dates_list:
    s = str(d)
    tackless.append(s[0:4]+s[5:7]+s[8:])
  return tackless

def divide_date(date1, date2, intervals):
  dates = [date1]
  delta = (date2-date1).total_seconds()/4
  for i in range(0, intervals):
    dates.append(dates[i] + timedelta(0,delta))
  return remove_tack(dates)

listdates = divide_date(d1, d2, 4)
print listdates
```

result:

> ['20150101 00:00:00', '20150115 12:00:00', '20150130 00:00:00', '20150213 12:00:00', '20150228 00:00:00']

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I accepted @Abhijit's answer since it cleans up my code a bit.

Comment: @Scott of course, the answer of Abhijit's is better, I also vote for her ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using Datetimeindex and Periods from Pandas, together with dictionary comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

begin = '20100101'
end = '20101231'

start = dt.datetime.strptime(begin, '%Y%m%d')
finish = dt.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y%m%d')

dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, end=finish, freq='D').tolist()
quarters = [d.to_period('Q') for d in dates]
df = pd.DataFrame([quarters, dates], index=['Quarter', 'Date']).T

quarterly_dates = {str(q): [ts.strftime('%Y%m%d') 
                            for ts in df[df.Quarter == q].Date.values.tolist()]
                           for q in quarters}

>>> quarterly_dates
{'2010Q1': ['20100101',
  '20100102',
  '20100103',
  '20100104',
  '20100105',
...
  '20101227',
  '20101228',
  '20101229',
  '20101230',
  '20101231']}

>>> quarterly_dates.keys()
['2010Q1', '2010Q2', '2010Q3', '2010Q4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending Abhijit's answer, you can specify the max amount of block for a specified frequency in minutes:

```
def date_range(start, end, freq, max_block):
    start = datetime.strptime(start,"%Y%m%d")
    end = datetime.strptime(end,"%Y%m%d")

    diff = timedelta(minutes=freq)*(max_block)
    chunk = int((end  - start ) / timedelta(minutes=freq) // (max_block))
    for i in range(chunk):
        yield (start + diff * i).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    yield end.strftime("%Y%m%d")

period = 365*2
endDate = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
startDate = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=period)).strftime("%Y%m%d")

list(date_range(startDate, endDate, 15, 5000))
```

Pretty useful in paginating REST api requests

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function, which includes the end date in date split.

```
from dateutil import rrule
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil.rrule import DAILY


def date_split(start_date, end_date, freq=DAILY, interval=1):
    """

    :param start_date:
    :param end_date:
    :param freq: refer rrule arguments can be SECONDLY, MINUTELY, HOURLY, DAILY, WEEKLY etc
    :param interval: The interval between each freq iteration.
    :return: iterator object
    """
    # remove microsecond from date object as minimum allowed frequency is in seconds.
    start_date = start_date.replace(microsecond=0)
    end_date = end_date.replace(microsecond=0)
    assert end_date > start_date, "end_date should be greated than start date."
    date_intervals = rrule.rrule(freq, interval=interval, dtstart=start_date, until=end_date)
    for date in date_intervals:
        yield date
    if date != end_date:
        yield end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the date rang by number of days. You can use the following snippet.

```
import datetime

firstDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
lastDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-03-30", "%Y-%m-%d")
numberOfDays = 15
startdate = firstDate
startdatelist = []
enddatelist = []

while startdate <= lastDate:
    enddate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=numberOfDays - 1)
    startdatelist.append(startdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"))
    if enddate > lastDate: enddatelist.append(lastDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))
    enddatelist.append(enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))
    startdate = enddate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

for a, b in zip(startdatelist, enddatelist):
    print(str(a) + "  -  " + str(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @Abhijit's answer, here's a version where one of the arguments is max_capacity_days based on which interval gets calculated internally.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Iterable

def date_groups( 
    start_at: datetime, 
    end_at: datetime,
    max_capacity_days: float) -> Iterable[datetime]:
    
    capacity = timedelta(days=max_capacity_days)
    interval = int( (end_at  - start_at ) / capacity) + 1
    for i in range(interval):
        yield (start_at + capacity * i)
    yield end_at
```

#### Usage

```py
>>> list(map(str, date_groups(datetime(2021,1,1), datetime(2021,5,1), 30))) 
['2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-31 00:00:00', '2021-03-02 00:00:00', '2021-04-01 00:00:00', '2021-05-01 00:00:00', '2021-05-01 00:00:00']

>>> list(map(str, date_groups(datetime(2021,1,1), datetime(2021,5,1), 50)))
['2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-02-20 00:00:00', '2021-04-11 00:00:00', '2021-05-01 00:00:00']
```

#### Practical Usage

Take an action for each date pair

```py
>>> dg = date_groups(datetime(2021,2,1, 1,33,33), datetime(2021,5,5), 30)
>>> dates = list(dg)
>>> for start_at, end_at in zip(dates[:-1],dates[1:]):
...     print(f"Delta in [{start_at}, {end_at}] = {(end_at-start_at)}")
...
Delta in [2021-02-01 01:33:33, 2021-03-03 01:33:33] = 30 days, 0:00:00
Delta in [2021-03-03 01:33:33, 2021-04-02 01:33:33] = 30 days, 0:00:00
Delta in [2021-04-02 01:33:33, 2021-05-02 01:33:33] = 30 days, 0:00:00
Delta in [2021-05-02 01:33:33, 2021-05-05 00:00:00] = 2 days, 22:26:27
```